# Some symbols don't effect cmd commands while others do

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I noticed that cmd seems to accept some characters at the ends of commands. for example all of the following function correctly:

```
cls.
cls;
cls(
cls\
cls+
cls=
cls\"whatever"
cls\$
cls\#
```

and these do not:

```
cls'
cls$
cls)
cls-
cls#
cls\/
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another one it accepts is `cls+` and `cls=`.

Comment: If you escape those broken characters with `\\` then they accept. It happens because of how cmd.exe interprets the command line, which is wildly varied from how GNU / Linux shell might interpret it: consistently. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/114147

Comment: Perhaps the question to ask is "Why are you putting random characters at the end of command line statements?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the batch parser.

`;,=` are general batch delimiters, so you can append/prepend them to the most commands without effect.

```
;,,=  ,=; echo hello
;,cls,;,,
```

The `.` dot can be appended to the most commands, as the parser will try to find a file named `cls` (without extension) `cls.exe` `cls.bat`, and when nothing is found then it takes the internal command.

The opening bracket is also a special charcter that the parser removes without error.

The `\` backslash is used as path delimiter, so sometimes it works but sometimes you could change even the command.

`cls\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`